# Storing and retrieving historical data using SQL / relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, constraints, spatial

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE DeptPeopleHistory (
  DEPT_ID INTEGER,
  PERSON_ID INTEGER,
  START_DATE INTEGER,
  END_DATE INTEGER,
  UNIQUE(DEPT_ID, START_DATE, PERSON_ID), -- works as sorted index.
  UNIQUE(PERSON_ID, START_DATE),
  UNIQUE(PERSON_ID, END_DATE),
  CONSTRAINT (START_DATE < END_DATE)
);
```

I have two needs. The first is to get all people that works on a given department at a given date. Currently I use this (semantically correct) query:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID FROM DeptPeopleHistory
WHERE
  DEPT_IT = :given_dept AND
  START_DATE <= :given_date AND :given_date < END_DATE
```

This is fast for small history table or querying recent data, but is slow for big history tables and old data, because the optimizer uses only the first index and there's no good way to deal with END_DATE. I've tried to add END_DATE to the first index, but query performance is the same. I guess it's because the sub-filter (DEPT_IT=:given_dept AND START_DATE <= :given_date) when applied to a sorted index (DEPT_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE, PERSON_ID) results in data with unsorted END_DATE, so (:given_date < END_DATE) still requires a sequential scan on the result.

My other need is to enforce the following constraint: a person cannot work at two departments at same time, nor twice at the same department. This means the following:

```
-- This must work for previously empty data:
INSERT INTO DeptPeopleHistory(DEPT_ID, PERSON_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
                      VALUES (1,       1,         20100501,   20100520);

-- This should cause constraint violation because the person already
-- works at dept 1 on days from 20100517 to 20100519:
INSERT INTO DeptPeopleHistory(DEPT_ID,   PERSON_ID, START_DATE, END_DATE)
                      VALUES (:any_dept, 1,         20100517,   20100523);
```

Another way to specify this constraint, is that for a given PERSON_ID, START_DATE must be the minimum or equals to END_DATE from another record.

Looking at those two needs, we actually need an efficient way for dealing with non-intersected ranges. Do you know some feature or construct in generic SQL or some specific database than can deal with these needs? Perhaps some "spatial database" feature?

The examples are in MySQL, but I need solutions that work on Oracle, SQL Server and FireBird. The solutions don't need to be portable across all such databases.

Comment: First, mySQL lacks the constraints required for temporal databases e.g. your table lacks a sequenced primary key i.e. allows overlapping dates for the same person + dept; even your `START_DATE < END_DATE` won't be checked when the table is updated. Second, (assuming you are looking for something open source), postgreSQL has better temporal support anyhow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding another index on DEPT_ID and END_DATE?  If you are using MySQL 5+, it may be able to do an index merge and use both that index and the DEPT_ID, START_DATE, PERSON_ID index.

As for your second question, I think the only way to enforce that type of constraint would be either via application logic or an insert/update trigger.

Answer (score 4):

As a starting point, I recommend the book Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL by Rick Snodgrass, available as [a free PDF download](http://www.e-bookspdf.org/free/developing-time-oriented-database-applications-in-sql.html). Looks like you can jump right in a chapter 5 and read through chapters 6 and 7 (but don't dismiss the alternative approaches in later chapters).

As regards implementation, postgreSQL currently has good temporal support generally and support for deferrable constraints (which is vital -- in SQL! -- for concepts such as sequenced keys).

Note there are other models for temporal databases e.g. [Date Darwen Lorentzos](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/TemporalData.Warwick.pdf).

Comment: The link of the book is broken. Try this one: http://www.e-bookspdf.org/free/developing-time-oriented-database-applications-in-sql.html

Answer (score 1):

Would it be possible to change the structure of table `DeptPeopleHistory` to?:

```
CREATE TABLE DeptPeopleHistoryDetail (
  DEPT_ID INTEGER,
  PERSON_ID INTEGER,
  WORK_DATE INTEGER,               --- why is that INT and not DATE by the way?
  UNIQUE(WORK_DATE, PERSON_ID)
);
```

Pros:

- You don't need to enforce any of the previous `UNIQUE` constraints, nor the `START_DATE < END_DATE` one.
- The second complex constraint(s) are magically solved too.

Cons:

- The `(1, 1, 20100501, 20100520)` from the previous example is now split into 20 rows. Not a real problem, I'd say. Relational databases are designed to handle many rows.
- To find `START_DATE` or `END_DATE` for a person in a department, a query has to be run. (if that is too slow, which I doubt, an additional table can be used)

---

Oh, and your slow query would be written as:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID FROM DeptPeopleHistoryDetail
WHERE
  DEPT_IT = :given_dept AND
  WORK_DATE = :given_date
```

---

With your current `DeptPeopleHistory` design, can you try the performance of the following query?

```
SELECT H.PERSON_ID
FROM DeptPeopleHistory H
  JOIN
    ( SELECT PERSON_ID
           , MAX(START_DATE) AS LATEST_START_DATE
      FROM DeptPeopleHistory
      WHERE
        DEPT_IT = :given_dept AND
        START_DATE <= :given_date
      GROUP BY
        PERSON_ID
    ) AS grp
    ON  H.DEPT_IT = :given_dept
    AND grp.PERSON_ID = H.PERSON_ID
    AND grp.LATEST_START_DATE = H.START_DATE
WHERE 
   :given_date < H.END_DATE
```

Comment: Might work for short periods, but I don't think it's scalable. Consider 5 years of 1000 employees - 1.8M rows - too much for a single table. Also, we might change precision from day to minutes, and that would multiply rows by 1440. By the way, I used INT instead of DATE just to get portable literals and make the example independent of data type.

Comment: @fernacolo: 1.8M rows x 12 bytes = 21MB. Not really big. If you have 30 years and 100K employees, yeah, it would get big.

Comment: If you increase precision to minutes, it's out of the question, too.

Comment: @ypercube If there are few people who left dept before :given_date, the query with a joined GROUP BY returns instantly! Very interesting logic!

Comment: @fernacolo: The problem with the original query is that it has to check two range conditions and it cannot use index on both `START_DATE` and `END_DATE`. This reconstruction tries to use the index of `PERSON_ID,START_DATE` in the group subquery and then an index with `END_DATE` in the outer query.

Comment: I'm not sure which index would benefit this most. Perhaps a simple `END_DATE` one. Can you try it? Or a complex `(DEPT_ID,PERSON_ID,START_DATE,END_DATE)`. Not really sure.

Comment: Or `(DEPT_ID,END_DATE)` as @Eric's suggestion.

Comment: @ypercube _The problem with the original query is that it has to check two range conditions and it cannot use index on both START_DATE and END_DATE_ Yes, I knew it. With a `DEPT_ID,END_DATE` index suggested by you and previously by @eric-petroelje, the original query returned instant results in MySQL and Oracle. I guess that will be the final solution.